# How to change the font size and color of a certain part of label in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I am using Arcmap 10.4. Now I have this label formatted in two lines, as shown below
[image: LabelExpression]

And it's shown in the map like:
[image]

Now I want the first line of the label, which is the Order# of the roads, to be bigger and probably with a different color while the second line remains the same.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  I would have a look at the [Formatting tags available in ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm).  This page shows how to [use the formatting tags](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/using-text-formatting-tags-about-text-formatting-t.htm) with some good examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can add different fonts, colors, styles to your text.
In this case the second line is blue Arial 6pt font, which will override the settings for the first line.

For example:

```
[Name] & vbcrlf & "<FNT name='Arial' size='6'><CLR blue = '255'>" & [Length] & "</CLR></FNT>" & " Miles"
```

Comment: This worked. Appreciate it