# Labeling 2 different fields, stacked, with different fonts and colors

Tags: labeling, arcgis-10.6

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6

I'm wanting to label some points features with the landing number and corresponding number of loads (I work in forest restoration).  I want them to be stacked and have different symbology.

For example, if landing 13.12 has 4 loads, I want it to be labeled something like this:

13.12 (in black)

*(4)* (in red)

I have something like the following from another post but I don't know how to change the text color or add italics:

```
def FindLabel ( [Name], [Loads] ):
  if  ([Name]) == "":
return [Name] + "\n" + "(" + [Loads] + ")"
  else:
    return ""
```

Comment: Please let us know what software you're using and tag your question with it as well.

Comment: <CLR red = '255'> (for red text) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217913/how-to-change-the-font-size-and-color-of-a-certain-part-of-label-in-arcgis

Comment: This is very helpful but I still have an issue.  This is what I have and it is displaying empty parenthesis on the items with no values, that I don't want labeled.  Currently I have: [Name] & vbCrLf & "<FNT name='Arial' size='8'><CLR red = '255'>" & "(" & [Loads] & ")" & "</CLR></FNT>"

Comment: That should be posted in a separate question.